# Android AChartEngine : Hide tick marks in axes

Tags: android, achartengine

Am trying out some graphs in an Android App with AChartEngine (version 1.2.0). I want to hide the tick marks in the axes (i.e. the small lines at each label displayed on the axes). I have marked two of them in red-colored-boxes in the screenshot below:

[image]

how do I do it? Can someone please help?
I read here (https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/issues/detail?id=336) that there is a multirenderer.setShowTickMarks(false); method. But am not getting to see that method in the XYMultipleSeries renderer API ( http://www.achartengine.org/content/javadoc/org/achartengine/renderer/XYMultipleSeriesRenderer.html ) on the Web, nor is that method recognized as defined in the IDE when I type it.

Comment: Just find the correct source see  https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/browse/trunk/achartengine/src/org/achartengine/renderer/DefaultRenderer.java?r=547

Comment: I did see that. Where do I download that jar from? I downloaded 1.0, 1.1, 1.2. None of them have this method in their API.

Comment: Have u seen the above?

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is:

```
mSetRenderer.setXLabels(0);



for(int i=0;i<=14;i++)
{
  if(i==4 || i==5)
  {
       // Do nothing(this will prevent to show ticks on 4th and 5th Value of X axis)
  }
  else
  {
      mSetRenderer.addXTextLabel(i,String.valueOf(i));
  }

}
```