# AChartEngine GraphicalView remove ticks

Tags: android, achartengine

Is it possible to remove the ticks on the axes in aChartEngine for Android? I've added pic in which the red square shows the tick that I couldn't find the API for removing:

[image: problem image]

**Update** This screenshot shows the properties that auto-suggest shows me for setting:

[image: Eclipse screenshot]

I'm using the stock aChartEngine jar.

**Another Update** I'm now compiling the jar from the source available here with my own customisations as per my need. I find this way a lot better than using the stock jar and feeling chained. The `setShowTickMarks(boolean val)` method is finally available :)

[image]

Comment: Do you want to remove **specific** ticks (i. e.: 3 and 5) or **all** together?

Comment: All together. The ticks in the image are only for demo :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Use `setShowTickMarks(false);`, as shown below:

[image]

**[EDIT]**

This is what I set in my `doRender()` method:

```
// ...

final XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer =
    new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer(4); // I use 4 series

// ...

setChartSettings
(
    renderer, CLS_Utils.yearUsing + " - " +
    getString(R.string.chart_top), "",
    getString(R.string.chart_left), minY, maxY,
    Color.parseColor(clr_navy), Color.WHITE
    Color.parseColor("#036"), Color.WHITE
);

renderer.setXLabels(12);

// ...
```

note the renderer object passed to my `setChartSettings()` method

And this is the full `setChartSettings()` method

```
private final void setChartSettings
(
    final XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer, final String title,
    final String xTitle, final String yTitle, final double yMin,
    final double yMax, final int axesColor, final int labelsColor
)
{
    renderer.setChartTitle(title);
    renderer.setXTitle(xTitle);
    renderer.setYTitle(yTitle);
    renderer.setYAxisMin(yMin);
    renderer.setYAxisMax(yMax);
    renderer.setAxesColor(axesColor);
    renderer.setLabelsColor(labelsColor);
}
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for taking some time out. Could you please tell me the type of `renderer` object? For `XYMultipleSeriesRenderer`, this method isn't available either in auto-suggest or the [documentation](http://www.achartengine.org/content/javadoc/index.html). Also, what version of aChart are you using? I'm using `1.1.0`.

Comment: I'm using the `XYMultipleSeriesRenderer`, as shown in the picture (see the function signature's first parameter) and the XY renderers. I'm using a customized version of the `1.1.0`. The customization was: I left only the LineChart and TimeChart graph (removed the Pie, Bar, and all the charts I didn't need) and added 2/3 features more I needed.

Comment: I see! So `setShowTickMarks(BOOL v)` isn't available by default. Could you point me to customise any `ChartView` for removing ticks?

Comment: Why do you say that `setShowTickMarks(boolean mShowTickMarks)` isn't available? The picture shows you clearly that **it's there**... try writing `renderer.set` and press Ctrl+SPACE

Comment: Hi, this is odd because I really don't see the `setShowTickMarks` option. I've updated the answer with what it shows on `renderer.set`'s auto-suggest. I had entered a link to the documentation of aChart in my first comment as well. Could you check to see if I'm using the same library as yours please.

Comment: Very funny. It's not any of my customizations (I don't use the `m` prefix, as in `mShowTickMarks`). My customizations apart, it's the same version.

Comment: I guess your answer is correct, although I'm still stuck. I also found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23856440/android-achartengine-hide-tick-marks-in-axes) with the same problem

Comment: I updated my answer, maybe it helps you more? The proposed solution won't print the label as well. Which is an ugly solution, imo.

Comment: Yeah, I would want the labels to show. One last question though: are you using the `jar` of aChartEngine or their source files?

Comment: The (re)compiled jar. Put in the libs folder and set in the Build Path. Anyway, the comment to the question you showed as an example point to https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/browse/trunk/achartengine/src/org/achartengine/renderer/DefaultRenderer.java?r=547, which has the `setShowTickMarks()` method.

Comment: I ended up compiling the source to jar myself with the `mShowTickMarks` property in `DefaultRenderer` set to `false`. I'll be keeping any future customisations in my own hands now :)

Comment: Welcome to the club! ;)